# Why is the integral between $\cos(x)$ and $\sin(x)$ between the intersections $\sqrt{2}$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, trigonometry

I just recently noticed, that the integral
$$\int_{-\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \cos(x) - \sin(x) dx = \sqrt{2}.$$

I know who to calculate all of it but I was quite surprised that the result is so simple. Is there maybe a graphical intuition behind this? Maybe one can use the diagonal of a unit square? Or is it just a "coincidence" and only holds because of the properties of $\cos(x)$?

Thanks for any answers, it's just a question out of interest.

Comment: Note that $\int_{-\pi/4}^{\pi/4}  \sin(x) dx = 0$ because the sine is odd.

Comment: You're right... But I can't shake the idea that it must have something to do with a square or something. The result is too perfect and in my 3 years of studying math I've learned that beautiful things almost always have a beautiful explanation :)

Comment: Also $\cos x - \sin x = \sqrt{2}\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4} - x\right)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just for fun:
$$
 [-\pi/ 4,  \pi/ 4] \ni \phi \mapsto c(\phi) = \left( \frac 12 - \frac{\sin \phi}{\sqrt 2},\frac 12 + \frac{\sin \phi}{\sqrt 2} \right)
$$
is a parametrization of the diagonal from $(1, 0)$ to $(0, 1)$ in the unit square $[0, 1]^2$, and its length is
$$
 \sqrt 2 = \int_{-\pi/4}^{\pi/4} \Vert c'(\phi) \Vert \, d\phi = \int_{-\pi/4}^{\pi/4} \sqrt{\cos^2(\phi)} \, d\phi =  \int_{-\pi/4}^{\pi/4} \cos(\phi) \, d\phi \, .
$$
Also $\int_{-\pi/4}^{\pi/4}  \sin(\phi) d\phi = 0$ because the sine is an odd function.

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I was looking for, I'll plot it later, but it seems great!